# App isn't designed for tablets

Tags: java, android, android-layout, google-play

I just got this:

Your Production APK needs to meet the following criteria:
Your layout should make use of the available space on tablets

In my Google Play Developer Console and I am wondering why is it showing when I tried a tablet emulator and my game runs fine on it? Is it something to be concerned or I have to change something in my apk.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kovach.gamger"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" 
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>`

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".AndroidLauncher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an e-mail to them and they said its all good because I was using Libgdx and they coudn't detect it and they fixed the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't created a separate layout for 7" or 10" tablets. Once you do that, your "error" in PlayStore will go away.

Have alook here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html